# Is it possible to add variables in config.xml?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have following xml:

```
<config>
    <global>
       <resources>
         <dbresource>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[1234]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[db_test]]></dbname>
            </connection>
        </dbresource>
      ...
  ...
```

I want to add all these Informations like(host, username, password and dbname) in admin_core_data and read them to connect to an external database. I know how to read/write data into admin_core_data using system.xml.

and I can connect to external database with config.xml but I need to let the employee to change it easily in "admin/system/configuration" because they cant edit xml files.

or any other idea guys, what to do in this situation?

Any advice guys?

Thank you..

Comment: To do this you need to add system.xml entries for each parameter. You can define default values for them in config.xml, and your class that connects using those parameters will need to read the values using `Mage::getStoreConfig('path/to/config')` and create the database connection instance using them

Comment: Do you mean local.xml, rather than config.xml, to connect external database?

Answer (score 1):

There is slight different approach by which you can implement the functionality. Add a new system.xml and then need to update the database configuration in madel files.

```
const XML_CONFIG_EDB_HOST = 'edb_settings/dbconnection/host';
const XML_CONFIG_EDB_DBNAME = 'edb_settings/dbconnection/dbname';
const XML_CONFIG_EDB_USERNAME = 'edb_settings/dbconnection/username';
const XML_CONFIG_EDB_PASSWORD = 'edb_settings/dbconnection/password';
const EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_NAME = 'edb_connection';

/* @var array */

protected $_config;

/* @var Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql */
protected $_connection;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_setConnection();
}

/**
 * Gets the Config Settings in the Admin Settings for DB Connection
 * @return array
 */
public function getConfig() {
    if (!$this->_config) {
        $this->_config = array();
        // Setting the Values from the Admin Config
        $this->_config['host'] = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_CONFIG_EDB_HOST);
        $this->_config['dbname'] = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_CONFIG_EDB_DBNAME);
        $this->_config['username'] = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_CONFIG_EDB_USERNAME);
        $this->_config['password'] = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_CONFIG_EDB_PASSWORD);

        // Setting the default Values
        $this->_config['initStatements'] = 'SET NAMES utf8';
        $this->_config['model'] = 'mysql4';
        $this->_config['type'] = 'pdo_mysql';
        $this->_config['pdoType'] = '';
        $this->_config['active'] = '1';
    }
    return $this->_config;
}

/**
 * Gets External DB Connection Resource
 *
 * @return Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
 */
public function getConnection() {
    if (!$this->_connection) {
        $this->_setConnection();
    }
    return $this->_connection;
}

private function _setConnection() {
    if (!$this->_connection) {
        $this->_connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->createConnection(self::EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_NAME, 'pdo_mysql', $this->getConfig());
    }
}

public static function getConnectionName() {
    return self::EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_NAME;
}
```

You can take a reference from below link
[External database configuration](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/external-database-connector.html)

Comment: Thank you, I ll test it now

Comment: I have a little problem, now magento creates 2 connections. from config.xml and from the model itself. how can I remove the connection from config? what do I need to call as resource? <entities>?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Magento standard way of getting store config.

`$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');`
sectionName, groupName and fieldName should be defined in `etc/system.xml` file of your module.

The above code will automatically fetch config value of currently viewed store.

Check some `system.xml` files to see how it is defined in Magento, so you can easily add it to your module.

Comment: Thank you, I ll test it now